# Pasar condicionalmente objeto props

Tags: reactjs, props

Estoy usando `react-slick` y quiero tener dos configuraciones diferentes para mobile y desktop. Actualmente tengo un objeto con la configuracion:

```
const sliderSettings = {
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  centerMode: true,
  ....
}
```

Y cuando llamo al slider hago

```
<Slider {...sliderSettings}/>
```

Ahora yo quiero tener un objeto diferente para mobile, ya tengo una variable `isMobile` disponible, y quiero hacer algo como

```
<Slider {isMobile ? {...sliderSettingsMobile} : {...sliderSettings}}/>
```

Probe de esta forma y algunas similares pero me arroja un error `"..." expected`

Alguien sabe cual es la forma correcta de enviar el objeto props condicionalmente?

Comment: crea una variable sliderSettingsProps cuyo valor cambia condicionalmente en el padre y al hijo pasale como prop sliderSettingsProps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has probado de esta manera?

```
const isMobile = true;
const desktopSettings = { centerMode: false };
const mobileSettings = { centerMode: true };
const settings = isMobile ? mobileSettings : desktopSettings;

<Slider {...settings} />
```

También lo puedes hacer así:

```
const isMobile = true;
const desktopSettings = { centerMode: false };
const mobileSettings = { centerMode: true };

<Slider {...(isMobile ? mobileSettings : desktopSettings)} />
```

Comment: Es la respuesta que buscaba, lamentablemente no me sirvio, al parecer el componente react-slick no acepta cambiar de props asi a la ligera, tengo que generar un componente u otro depende de la situacion. De todas maneras, la segunda solucion responde a mi pregunta. Aceptada.